# Easiest way to compile a Simulink model into executable?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need to turn a complex simulink model that runs in realtime, receive & send data using sharedmemory and socket every 100ms, contains exernal C++ callback functions(for sharedmemory and socket), into an executable. There is no need for UI like graphs or buttons(maybe print some log but nothing more).

I'm quite new to simulink, what is the easiest way to compile such a simulink model into an executable? Would be great if there is also a super detailed guide.

Also a side question - is using C function block(and converting structs to buses) the preferred way to use sharedmemory and socket in simulink? Any better substitution?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a tutorial and documentation, its an entire product in fact. https://uk.mathworks.com/products/simulink-compiler.html

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes I'm  aware of this simulink compiler, and it seems it's already intergrated in matlab 2022? I also found a guide about deploying app using this. But I can't say I fully understand how to do it, step by step, in my exact situation...

Comment: I am sorry, but this is not a tutorial webpage, and the MATLAB webpage was very very thorough documentation on how to do it. We are not trying to replace them in any shape or form in StackOverflow.